# How to retrieve Google calendar entries using service account and.NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am getting the following error when using a service account + impersonation to retrieve Google calendar entries:

Error:"access_denied", Description:"", Uri:""

I can create events using both user and service account flow (no impersonation). I can retrieve calendars using both user and service account flow (with and without impersonation). I can retrieve calendar events with only user flow.

On a related matter, I noticed that using the oAuth2 user flow the returned events include those that I am not an attendee, so I am unclear if impersonation should filter returned events to only those that I am an attendee.

Here is the service account + impersonation code:

```
string serviceAccountEmail = "...@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath("~") + @"\bin\key.p12", "notasecret",
    X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new
    ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {  Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }, User="my email here" }.FromCertificate
    (certificate));     

BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential;
initializer.ApplicationName = "Google Calendar Sample";
service = new CalendarService(initializer);

IList list = service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items;  // throws error

foreach (CalendarListEntry calendar in list)
   DisplayFirstCalendarEvents(calendar);
```

Getting a Calendar directly also throws the same error:

```
Calendar cal1 = service.Calendars.Get("my personal calendar id").Execute();  //throws same error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our Calendar API team checked that one and they found out the following:

1. You tried to access events of lbl.gov_7d...7oag@group.calendar.google.com using service account  628725648769-cda....3djjj@developer.gserviceaccount.com. Am I correct?
   It looks like you performed successful event insert operations using that service account on the 12th.
2. There are no failed requests coming from that account to that calendar.
3. However, that service account also accessed lbl.gov_oe10h.....un9c@group.calendar.google.com on the 12th and at the beginning, operations were returning 404, latter 200 (Maybe someone changed ACLs for this calendar in the meantime?).

Makes any sense?