# System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied

Tags: c#, .net, azure

When i am trying to access my website hosted on windows azure, i get this error message. please see the stack trace below. I am using HttpClientInitializer in my project to access google analytic services.

```
[HttpListenerException (0x5): Access is denied]
System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config() +333
System.Net.HttpListener.Start() +297
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.<ReceiveCodeAsync>d__6.MoveNext() +188
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573272/googlewebauthorizationbroker-authorizeasync-hangs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783411/c-net-oauth-unlimited-load-time-access-to-the-path-google-apis-auth-is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve Google calendar entries using service account and.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941001/how-to-retrieve-google-calendar-entries-using-service-account-and-net)

Comment: None of the above links works for me?